# When coming from Google, Stack Overflow opens itself in a new tab and closes the old one with Google history

Tags: support, bug, google, firefox

I just realized that there is a possible bug with how you are treating incoming requests from Google redirects.

If you open a Stack Overflow link from Google, it seems like you are opening a new tab with that link, and closing the tab with the history of where you came from with Google, so you can't navigate back to Google, if the question you clicked in Google is not the question that you wanted to see.

If this is the intended way this is supposed to function, in my opinion this is quite malicious, as it forces people to stay on your site.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I'm on Windows 10, latest Chrome and when I open a SO link from google, I can use the back button to go back to google. Do you have any extensions installed that might interfere with these links?

Comment: ah, it seems this is only happening with Firefox on Ubuntu, tried this on FF on Win10, and it worked just fine

Comment: And if try Bing / Duck Duck Go? Is that the same?

Comment: The same behavior happens with both those search engines

Comment: " in my opinion this is quite malicious" - or buggy... browser buggy.

Comment: @Gimby Indeed, follow Hanlon's Razor: "Never ascribe to malice, that which can be explained by stupidity" :)

Answer (score 9):

If you are on page A and open a link to page B; page A, the browser and its extensions decide what happens. Page B has no say in it.

Therefore this behavior is not a bug of Stack Overflow as it is page B in this case.